# node.js express - mime type woff font returned as text/plain type

Tags: node.js, express, mime, woff

I am using node-mime to set the correct mime type for woff font. Still not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var express = require('express')
var mime = require('mime');

...

express.static.mime.define({
 'application/x-font-woff': ['woff'],
 'application/font-woff': ['woff']
});
```

Cheers
@harishvc

Comment: Are you using an old version of Express? Even without the `define`'s it serves `woff` files with the correct mime type for me (`Express@3.4.6`). Although I don't understand why you're declaring two mime types for the same extension...

Comment: Yes I was using a older version of Express. I have upgraded Express now but still no progress. I now get 404 on woff files! Files exist on the server but can't access via http. Any assistance?

Comment: Solved! I was using fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3 and for some strange reason Express returns 404! I changed the logic to fontawesome-webfont.woff and it works.

Comment: Hi Can you please clarify how you solved it? I am facing the same issue with v4.0.4. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing a proper route to serve your fonts. serve-static will already provide the correct mime types.

You can easily serve static resources in your project with [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static). If you're already using `serve-static` check that you're actually sending the font when it is requested.